# How to use Sqlite-net Extensions for Windows 7?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I used sqlite-net library and I was creating sqlite connection similar to this :
`var db = new SqliteConnection(path);`

But Sqlite-net Extensions demand using `Sqlite.Net.SqliteConnection` that needs as a first parameter `ISQlitePlatform` and I didn't know what should I pass there for Windows 7 platform . 
https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Comment: is there not one for the full .net framework?

Comment: @DanielA.White what do you mean? I am talking about this lib - https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL

Comment: Please provide all relative info, don't force us to guess. Obviously you are **not** using [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki). It looks like you are using the [SQLite.Net PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) package which requires another platform-specific implementation package. So the question is, where is the implementation package for Windows?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos have I ever said that I am using System.Data.SQLite? There 's nothing to guess - all details are provided.

Comment: You mentioned "SQLite.Net", not "SQLite.Net PCL". SQLite.Net is essentially the name used for System.Data.SQLite. There is another project called "SQLite-Net" by Tim Heuer that has twice the downloads of the one you used. Finally, another "SQLite-net" is a dead project, from which "SQLite.NET PCL" was forked. The github site provides a link to all implementation packages

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I said I am using sqlite-net, not Sqlite.Net .

Comment: That's Tim Heuer's package, not the one you posted. Check the exact package names and links

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos okay,I made a small mistake in comments providing the wrong link. Everything including libraries that I am using were provided in the original question

Comment: You have to be specific, especially when using uncommon packages, to avoid downvotes and close votes. I didn't downvote by the way, I guessed something was fishy and tried to find out. It isn't a small error, when you mention the wrong library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70791/discussion-between-ig-melnyk-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Win32-specific package to your solution, [SQLite.Net PCL - Win32 Platform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32/) and pass an instance of `SQLitePlatformWin32` to the connection constructor.

Please note that `SQLite.Net PCL` is relatively obscure at this time, with half the downloads of the [SQLite-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net/) package by Tim Heuer, and 1/10 of the downloads of what most people consider `SQLite.Net`, the [System.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/) package.

To avoid confusion, it would be better if you specified explicitly the package you mean, including the link to it.